# ¿Por qué no se evalúa la condición?

Tags: java, hilos

Hola estoy intentando implementar una cola, es decir tengo una serie de hilos que obtienen un id, y van a una cola la idea es que si la cola tiene 10 elementos no acepte ningún mas, y la tarea espere 2 segundos antes de volver a intentar introducir el id en la cola.

Para realizar esto tengo el siguiente código:

La clase principal donde creo 100 tareas que se van a introducir en la cola, y el QueueCleaner, que va a quitar un elemento de la cola cada 1 segundos

```
public class Main {

    public static QueueOfTickets queueOfTickets = new QueueOfTickets();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new QueueCleaner());
        t2.start();

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task());
            t1.start();
        }       
    }   
}
```

La cola de tickets

Esta es la condición que no se cumple, por que le indico que solo si la cola es menor de 10 agregue un elemento sin embargo llega a agregar 11 o 12 elementos mas

```
public class QueueOfTickets {
    public static int id = 0;
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public QueueOfTickets() {}

    public boolean addToQueue(Integer integer) {
        if(queue.size() < 10) {
            queue.add(integer);
            System.out.println("Int " + integer + " add to queue, size: " + queue.size());
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void poll() {
        System.out.println("Deque: " + queue.poll());
    }
}
```

Task
Esta es la clase que va a agregar elementos a la cola

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    int id = 0;
    public void run(){
        QueueOfTickets.id++;
        id = QueueOfTickets.id;
        while(!Main.queueOfTickets.addToQueue(id)) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   } 
}
```

Y esta es la tarea que quita cada segundo un elemento de la cola

```
public class QueueCleaner implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            Main.queueOfTickets.poll();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   } 
}
```

Cuando ejecuto esto ni de lejos llego a poder insertar 100 elementos llegado un punto solo retorna null, ademas de que introduce mas de un elementos sobre el total de los permitidos en la condición

Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que veo aca, es que de los 100 threads que insertan en la cola, no hay semaforos, ni zonas donde no se puede parar la ejecucion, ni nada que controle que un código debe forsozamente ejecutarse todo junto.

Vos decis que lanzas 100 threads. Bueno, juguemos con solamente 3

T1 arranca
T2 arranca
T3 arranca

Supongamos que solamente vamos a admitir 1 elemento en la cola.

Nuestro problema es la siguiente funcion:

```
public boolean addToQueue(Integer integer) {
    if(queue.size() < 10) {
        queue.add(integer);
        System.out.println("Int " + integer + " add to queue, size: " + queue.size());
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Vamos a jugar un ratito y simular el procesador...

T1 ejecuta las siguientes lineas:

```
if(queue.size() < 1) { //y le da true y pasa el puntero a la siguiente linea
```

Y el procesador saca ese proceso, y dispara T2 que ejecuta

```
if(queue.size() < 1) { //y le da true y pasa el puntero a la siguiente linea
```

Y de nuevo el procesador saca ese proceso, y dispara T3 que ejecuta

```
if(queue.size() < 1) {
        queue.add(integer);
        System.out.println("Int " + integer + " add to queue, size: " + queue.size());
```

Ahora la cola ya tiene un elemento, pero para T1 y T2, no tenia nada. con lo cual, el procesador saca T3 y vuelve a ejecutar T1

```
queue.add(integer);
```

Y ahora tu cola, tiene 2 elementos.

Para evitar estas cosas, se usan semaforos que impiden la ejecucion de ciertos bloques al mismo tiempo.

En Java se usa [Synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) a nivel de metodos o codigo, para evitar que otro thread entre en esa parte al mismo tiempo.

En tu caso, deberias usarlo dentro del metodo addToQueue (**nota, hay que probar esto muy bien**)

```
public boolean addToQueue(Integer integer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(queue.size() < 10) {
            queue.add(integer);
            System.out.println("Int " + integer + " add to queue, size: " + queue.size());
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```